# What to do if Recyclerview is showing, then hiding item again

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have this problem sometimes, when after I request Firebase Firestore Documents, it RETRIEVES ALL THE DATA, shows it correctly in the RecyclerView, but then the Data just disappears after one second.

`adapter.getItemCount();` shows, there are Items. I just can´t figure it out...

Here is the retrieval code for the first Cardview:

```
void getData(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference doc =db.collection("data").document("codes");
    doc.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            userWorkList.clear();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    final ArrayList codes = (ArrayList) document.get("code");
                    System.out.println("Codes: "+codes);
                    for(int i=0;i<codes.size();i++) {
                        DocumentReference doc =db.collection("codes").document(codes.get(i).toString());
                        final int finalI = i;
                        doc.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()) {
                                        if(document.get("code")!=null) {
                                            HashMap codeMap = (HashMap) document.get("code");
                                            if (codeMap.toString().toLowerCase().contains(user.getDisplayName().toLowerCase())){
                                                userWorkList.add(new User_Work_View_Row(codes.get(finalI).toString(), user.getEmail(), "", finalI));
                                                System.out.println(codes.get(finalI) + " FOUND");
                                                //WorkAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
                                            if(finalI==codes.size()-1){
                                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        System.out.println("Execute Handler");
                                                        if(WorkAdapter.getItemCount()==0&&userWorkList.size()==0){
                                                            System.out.println("NO ITEMS");
                                                            getData();
                                                            //handler.postDelayed(this, 2500);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                };
                                                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                                                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                                WorkAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    //WorkAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //userWorkProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The adapter Init:

```
    RecyclerView list = root.findViewById(R.id.currentUserWork);
    LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    LayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
    LayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    list.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
    WorkAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    WorkAdapter.setGlobalContext(getContext());
    list.setAdapter(WorkAdapter);
```

The Adapter Code really isn´t important because it only shows the Title of the next RecyclerView.

I would love to share a video of it happening, but exactly when I want it to disappear, it shows correctly.

Has someone experienced this sort of thing before or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, I **THINK** I figured it out, I had 0dp for my RecyclerView instead of wrap_content.
But I need to run it a few times before I am certain..

Answer (score 0):

possible trouble in code:

you makes loop

```
for (int i=0;i<codes.size();i++) {
```

and in the loop you creates many `OnCompleteListener`s

the problem here is, that they could be finished in different order.

so your `finalI` could come before all results are done

**UPDATE**

To solve this problem

1. create global variable `int requestsLeft`
2. after `if (document.exists()) {` set `requestsLeft = codes.size()`
3. after `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {` make `requestsLeft--`
4. instead of `if(finalI==codes.size()-1){` you can now check `if (requestsLeft == 0) {`

so you are sure, that all requests are done

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I don´t know any other method to check a lot of documents.. The `codes` array are the Document names I have to check.

Comment: @DanielTerletzkiy please see updated answer. Have you solved your main problem?